# Specific word if it exists?

Tags: single-word-requests, psychology

A word or a feeling that describes specifically when ONLY meeting new people?

Comment: Regarding the *feeling*, it typically depends on who the new people are; what kind of person each of them are; why they are meeting you and you are meeting them; or whether or not you know *of* them or anything about them, for that matter... but regarding *words*? I don't think so.

Comment: Please note, the system has flagged your question for closure as "low-quality because of its length and content." Please [edit] your question to avoid closure - for example, add a sample sentence showing how your word would be used. For further guidance, see [ask], and take the [Tour]. :-)

Comment: One thing you should clarify is what kind of feeling you mean. People meeting new people (or new people only) can have all kinds of feelings, from joy to fear, from excitement to boredom...

Answer (score 2):

A phrase that applies in the context of meeting new people is [first impression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_impression_(psychology)):

> [Wikipedia]
>
> In psychology, a first impression is the event when one person first encounters another person and forms a mental image of that person. Impression accuracy varies depending on the observer and the target (person, object, scene, etc.) being observed. First impressions are based on a wide range of characteristics: age, race, culture, language, gender, physical appearance, accent, posture, voice, number of people present, and time allowed to process. The first impressions individuals give to others could greatly influence how they are treated and viewed in many contexts of everyday life.

Despite this quotation (Wikipedia is not the greatest of sources, but it seemed adequate here), you can also have first impressions of places, things, and ideas.

By definition, a *first* impression can only be had when something is new.